# How to add hashing in lazyload css in angular.json

Tags: css, hash, angular6, lazy-loading

We create lazyload in css folder.But when we build the project the css folder inside the dist folder ,the .css file is not hashing.We want the lazy loaded css file name should be like styles.6fc199501f143ca330d5.css.

Comment: You'll need to provide an example of what you've already tried and/or your existing angular configuration.

Comment: any luck, @Chayanika Halder?

Answer (score 0):

You create lazy-loadable hashed styles with Webpack.

My Angular CLI version: 8.3.19

1. ng new lazy-load-css --style css
2. Open the `angular.json` and remove `styles.css` from styles array.
3. Create `style-loader.js` in the `src` folder and then replace with the following code:

```js
import styles from './styles.css';
const node = document.createElement('style');
node.textContent = styles;
document.querySelector('head').appendChild(node);
```

4. Add the `ngOnInit` method in the `AppComponent` like below:

```
  ngOnInit() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      import('src/style-loader');
    }, 1500);
  }
```

> See [Webpack `import()`](https://webpack.js.org/api/module-methods/#import-1) function. Also you can see [Webpack magic comments](https://webpack.js.org/api/module-methods/#magic-comments) for chunk naming, etc.

5. Add a style to `styles.css` to see changes. I added the background color style.
6. Run the app

[image: lazy-loadable-css-hashing]

Run the `ng build --prod` to see the hash